# changing scroll top inside angular directive doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my directive I wrote my logic for dynamic pagination (lazy loading), each time the user scroll to the bottom of the page I append more elements to it , this works fine but I want to to **change the scroll position** after that but it doesn't work. 
This is my code :

```
 link: function(scope, element) {

            var usersArea = $(".usersArea");

            usersArea.bind("scroll", function() {

                var scrollHeight = $(this)[0].scrollHeight;
                var scrollTop = $(this)[0].scrollTop;
                var clientHeight = $(this)[0].clientHeight;
                var downloadMore = scrollHeight - scrollTop - clientHeight < 50;

                if (downloadMore) {
                    var childScope = scope.$new();    

                    usersContainer = scope.displayPortion(usersContainer);
                    if (usersContainer) {
                        $compile(usersContainer)(childScope);
                        //This doesn't work !!
                        $(this)[0].scrollTop = 500;
                    }
                }
            });    
}
```

I tried to change the scroll position using native javascript and with JQuery but nothings seem to work, any suggestions ?

Comment: Do you have fiddle/plunker demo? try also to pospone that set via for example `var self = this; setTimeout(function(){ $(self)[0].scrollTop = 500; })`...

Comment: sorry I don't have any fiddle for that, my code can't be applied on it, and the code is very big to be posted, I will try this , thanks.

Comment: You are really awesome !!! the timeout did the trick thanks !

Comment: can you add this in an answer ?,  just to let others benefit from that.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the answer to another question :) let me re-make this one..

Comment: So, I posted that suggestion as an answer and you may accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `compile` is not immediate procedure I would suggest to postpone any operations with the result of compiling. The easiest (but not the best) way is to use simple timer:

```
  var elt = $(this)[0];
  var scrollHeight = elt.scrollHeight;
  var scrollTop = elt.scrollTop;
  var clientHeight = elt.clientHeight;
  var downloadMore = scrollHeight - scrollTop - clientHeight < 50;

  if (downloadMore) {
      var childScope = scope.$new();    
      usersContainer = scope.displayPortion(usersContainer);
      if (usersContainer) {
          $compile(usersContainer)(childScope);
          setTimeout(function() {
            elt.scrollTop = 500;
          });
      }
  }
```